Create a mixed multi row and multi column table
Please help me create a table like in the image.
I have been looking for similar questions but there is no answer.


No. There are lots of similar questions on this site. Please try to search.

I tried to customize and modify sample codes but I have been still struggling that why I posted here

You should show what you have tried. An MWE starting from \documentclass and ending with \end{document} is necessary.

As stated above, please provide a MWE. There are a lot of different packages for tabular material, so it is essential to know your approach. What about this Q&A or this? A very quick search already shows a lot of similar questions on this site.

The multirow package might be useful in this case.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
% \setlength\extrarowheight{1mm} % optional parameter in case you prefer more sep


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Number of\\X (\#)}}   & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{XX-XXX} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{YY-YY} \\\cline{2-9}
                                                    & \makecell{a\\(unit)} & \makecell{b\\(\#)} & \makecell{c\\(unit)} & \makecell{d\\(unit)} & \makecell{a\\(unit)} & \makecell{b\\(\#)} & \makecell{c\\(unit)} & \makecell{d\\(unit)} \\\hline 
                                                    &                      &                    &                      &                      &                      &                    &                      &\\\hline
                                                    &                      &                    &                      &                      &                      &                    &                      &\\\hline
                                                    &                      &                    &                      &                      &                      &                    &                      &\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}



THank you! @Lucas
